# Animation object position..origin point, proper pivot

Tags: modeling, animation, vertices, origin, transform-orientation

Can someone please tell me a better way to keep objects aligned when animating them. What i'm currently doing is moving the cursor and the origin point to a vertice at the corner of the object and pivoting from there  and every time i run the animation the lid is slightly off its axis and i have to realign it. How do i make sure it stays aligned after running the animation?.[image: pivot]

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long way of doing it, but you can type the exact position of the xyz locations and rotations for each object.

As these are in a straight line, technically two of the locations should be identical for each object, and the rotation should be the same for all of them.

So find one that's in the correct position, then copy paste the location and rotation to all the others. You'd only then need to alter the x or y (not sure from the screenshot) of each to space them out.

That's how I'd do it but maybe there's a better more efficient way.

Comment: Thank you it's working.

Comment: Ok. Good to hear!